# Moral and economic development paradox?

Tags: reference-request, data-request, economic-growth, development, development-economics

I have often listen to the old man who criticized the lack of morality in the Chinese people nowadays: "*To get more money, break through to the bottom line to get more money!*"

Is there a contradiction between economic development and morality? Are there any countries that are highly ethical standards that develop very well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is some evidence that immoral behavior, as exemplified though political corruption, is bad for economic development. The body of literature is large and to the extent that I am familiar with it, some corruption can "grease the wheels" and hasten development. In general, massive amounts of corruption is seen as a serious hinderence to development.

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=corruption+and+economic+development&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=8YxkVbyICYqzoQT5moKIBA&ved=0CBoQgQMwAA

Also, I think that the utilitarian ideal suggests that all else being equal, more wealth and consumption is better. This implies that economic development carries a moral weight. That is to say, an ethical society should develop economically, to raise the standard of living and reduce suffering.